# How do I measure the time it takes a for loop to run to completion?

Tags: python

I'm trying to debug the length of time `for i in image_list:` takes to complete, there are two possibilities as to how this loop ends. Either true or false. True occurs if it finds a positive image match, and false occurs if it doesn't.

I'm using:

```
loop_time = time.time()
```

And:

```
# debug the loop rate
print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time.time() - loop_time)))
loop_time = time.time()
```

To debug the time. The issue I have is in the logic below. If I leave the `#debug` code section where it is, I only get the time of the last iteration if `match_points` is true.

If I move the `#debug` code section above `match_points` I get the time of each individual iteration rather than the time it takes for the whole `for` loop to run.

I want to know, how long it takes for `for i in image_list` to run, regardless of where it stops running. **How do I achieve this?**

```
def detection(image_list):

    # start timer
    loop_time = time.time()

    for i in image_list:  
        needle_img = i[0]
           
        match_points = #someMethod
        match_image = #someMethod

        if match_points:
            match_image = #someMethod
          
            # debug the loop rate
            print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time.time() - loop_time)))
            loop_time = time.time()     

            return True      
    return False
```

Comment: You can duplicate your print() just before your `return False`

Comment: That's giving me the time of the very last iteration only, rather than the time it takes for the whole to run.

Comment: Well, one of the answers begs to differ.

Comment: It should accurately report how long the loop took (up until it stopped). gchapuis's answer gives a less repetitive way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Just an addition. use `process_time` instead of `time`. It's more accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a boolean as the return value to only have a single return statement. I find it easier to read that way. And use a break statement instead.

```
def detection(image_list):
    res = False
    # start timer
    loop_time = time.time()

    for i in image_list:  
        needle_img = i[0]
       
        match_points = #someMethod
        match_image = #someMethod

        if match_points:
            match_image = #someMethod
            res = True
            break
    # debug the loop rate
    print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time.time() - loop_time)))       
    return res
```

Comment: That's only giving me the time of the last iteration rather than the whole loop. The loop takes about 26 seconds, but the output is `FPS 0.039287800705053444`

Comment: @mak47 Are you overwriting loop_time in your loop ?

Comment: I am not @gchapuis

Comment: @mak47 Are you certain that the 26 second timing is only for the loop and not something else before or after the loop ?

Comment: 100% certain, I print out some other debugging information each iteration. It's an object detection function and the screen it's running it;s detection on also has a timer visual timer on it so I can literally count out the loops myself to a fair degree of accuracy. I'm about to attempt to optimise the speed so I'd like to do it code.

Comment: Are your #someMethods asynchronous ?

Comment: I call two of them from a different script but they run in my main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244546/discussion-between-gchapuis-and-mak47).

Answer (score 4):

A nice tool is [`tqdm`](https://tqdm.github.io/). It will display a progress bar, along with loops per second, etc. It can be heavily customized as well.

In your code, you would simply change:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

# ...

for i in tqdm(image_list, unit='F'):
    # ...
```

At the end, you'd get a nice summary, e.g. (in a Jupyter notebook):

[image]

**Edit**
If you don't want to display the progress during the iteration, but only as a summary at the end, you have several options. One of them is:

```py
it = tqdm(image_list, unit='F', delay=1e9)
for i in it:
    # do stuff

# and at the end:
it.display()
```

Comment: That looks incredibly useful and I'd like to explore although I'm despite pip installing fine it's giving me a missing import error sadly

Comment: The import error doesn't stop it from running it seems, but unfortunately that's giving me an output every single iteration rather than just at the end. Issue being each iteration prints out a lot of information to the terminal as is, so interspacing with more makes it difficult to debug on the fly.

Comment: Re. import errors: you may have an inconsistent environment, FWIW, I avoid `pip` at all costs, as I found it almost always destroys my environments -- I use `conda` or `mamba` or `poetry`.

Comment: Re. the progress interfering with the output of your loop: see the **edit** in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the standard library `cProfile` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html))

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the time it would take if all the images were computed you can estimate that time

```
def detection(image_list):
    # start timer
    t0 = time.time()
    nbLoop = len(image_list)

    for i, img in enumerate(image_list):
        needle_img = img[0]

        match_points =  # someMethod
        match_image =  # someMethod

        if match_points:
            match_image =  #    someMethod

            # debug the loop rate
            print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time.time() - loop_time)))
            loop_time = time.time()

            return True

        percent_done = (i+1) / nbLoop
    ts = time.time() - t0
    time_remaining = ts / (percent_done ) -ts
    print('percent_done',percent_done, 'time remaining',time_remaining, 'elapse time',ts )
    return False
```

Comment: `percent_done = (i+1) / nbLoop
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple` is there an easy way to wrap the int into a tuple?

Comment: you have to check the nbLoop  value it should be an int and represent the number of images contained in image_list

Comment: @ymmx Did you mean to `enumerate` the list? Currently, `i` is each item of the original list, not an index.

Comment: sorry I'm wrong

Comment: yes, CrazyChucky's right

Comment: `needle_img = i[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` now with that change

Comment: @ymmx Why not edit your answer?

Comment: @CrazyChucky you're 100% right :)

Comment: That's now giving me this: `percent_done 0.9777777777777777 time remaining 0.5260235775600783` each loop and then `percent_done 1.0 time remaining 0.0` at the very end. I need the total time rather than each time.

Comment: we can print the ts time too, I edited the code

Comment: That does give me time elapsed at the end, but it's also still giving me an update each iteration. Can we skip it individual prints and only print the very last one?

Comment: the post of @gchapuis give's you what you want then

Comment: put the print outside the loop. I edited the post

Comment: That works! Oddly the loop is actually running slightly faster (about 2 seconds) with that code added, very strange. Thank you!